# Записать строковое значение в реквизит ссылочного типа

Tags: 1с

Загрузил в свою базу данных каталог товаров с BTT. Необходимо записать значение ПартНомера(полученного в виде строки) в реквизит справочник ссылочного типа. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Справочнике (о котором идет речь) необходимо создать новый элемент (или найти уже существующий по ПартНомеру) в реквизит записать ссылку на этот элемент.

Answer (score 0):

Все просто. Получили например номенклатуру: "Стул МК"
Нам надо передать ссылку на данную номенклатуру в какой то справочник.
Для этого надо найти ссылку на данную номенклатуру.
пишем:
НоменклатураСсылка = Справочники.Номенклатура.НайтиПоНаименованию("Стул МК");
Если найдет, то будет ссылка на номенклатуру, если нет, тогда будет пустая ссылка